# What is a good, free PHP charting suite?

Tags: php, charts, graph

All I will be doing is basic line graphs. Any experiences anyone might share would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *(related)* http://www.codediesel.com/php/6-excellent-charting-libraries-for-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openflashchart: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/

A bit beyond simple line charts. LGPL licensed so it's commercial friendly.

For really simple charts take a look at the [jQuery sparklines plugin](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/). It does some really wonderful things actually.

Answer (score 1):

[JPGraph](https://jpgraph.net/) is a very powerful charting library for PHP

Comment: Unfortunately JPGraph doesn't support yet PHP 8 and it fails when using their basic functions - https://groups.google.com/g/jpgraph

Answer (score 1):

Not really PHP, but I find amchart really easy to implement and they look great: http://www.amcharts.com/

Might also check out Google's API: http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) that looks pretty good.

Comment: pChart hasn't been updated in a while. It doesn't work out of the box with PHP newer than 5.1.4 (it uses deprecated functions). Not too difficult to fix though.

Comment: Licensing might be an issue. It's GPL only.

Comment: pChart is already 13 years old. It won't run now.

Answer (score 0):

use [FLOT](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), which is a plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)