# I want to make a chart with mysql in PHP

Tags: graph, charts

I want to make nice charts on my website, how can I do this, not to difficult, in PHP?

The data of the charts have to come from my database in mysql..

Comment: have you tried researching PHP chart tutorials on Google first?

Comment: This is a duplicate of other existing quesitons, look at the links in the right column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110839/best-graph-and-diagram-toolset-for-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395541/graphs-charts-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805997/what-is-a-good-free-php-charting-suite and more...

Answer (score 1):

You have several 3rd party libraries that can make the work much easier and less error prone, here are some good ones: [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) , [GraPHpPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/) , also google charts may be helpful. Also [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) are nice and fancy.

There are many others which can match your needs, I think these are the best. All have lots of tutorials around the web.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com).
Just visit the link

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=nl-NL

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a php library for creating graphs

like [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) or  [Gphpchart](http://www.malaiac.com/tools/13-new-gphpchart-class-php-with-google-chart-api.html)

Graphs are about nodes and vertices you can`t make them by just simple creating a simple scripts